# Using a local proxy auto configuration (.pac) file for proxy settings from a chrome extension

Tags: proxy, google-chrome-extension, pac

I want to modify the proxy settings of chrome using an extension.
I want it to use a local .pac file which is present in my extension's root folder.
I tried following ways to refer this pac file:

```
settings.pacScript.url = "proxyFile.pac"; 
settings.pacScript.url = "chrome-extension://adcccdddeeefffggghhhiiijjjkkklll/proxyFile.pac";
```

These two methods do not work.
I tried using "chrome://net-internals" to inspect what is happening and found the following(there was no **file not found** error or **pac javascript** error):

```
PROXY_CONFIG_CHANGED  
                        --> old_config =
                               Use DIRECT connections.
                        --> new_config =
                               Use DIRECT connections.
```

Whereas the following two approaches work:

```
settings.pacScript.url = "C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\myChromeExtension\\proxyFile.pac";
settings.pacScript.url = "http://www.example.com/proxyFile.pac";
```

Now since I want to refer to the local file in my extension, I cannot use http url.For using file url, how do I know the url of my extension's root folder?

Looking for help on this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In a chrome extension, you can get a URL for a file inside your extension with [`chrome.extension.getURL`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-getURL). This will return a `chrome-extension://` URL.

In your case, you want:

```
settings.pacScript.url = chrome.extension.getURL("proxyFile.pac");
```